# What does the BY in CC BY and CC BY-SA etc mean?

Tags: copyright

What does `BY` refer to in the context of this license name please: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/

I'm sure it's something really obvious that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that a licensee has to say who the work is "by"—that is, attribute it to the creator.

> Licensees may copy, distribute, display and perform the work and make derivative works and remixes based on it only if they give the author or licensor the credits (attribution) in the manner specified by these. Since version 2.0, all Creative Commons licences require attribution to the creator and include the BY element.

There's more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license).

Comment: Got it.  So it's not an acronym it literally means "by".  Thank you!